# Dell equivalent of Cisco Span

Tags: cisco, dell, voip, gigabit

We are in the process of upgrading out network to Gigabit to the desktop.
Currently we are using this equipment...

```
CUCM (Cisco Unified Communication Manger 8.0.3.20000-2)
Cisco 2821 Integrated Service Router
6x Cisco WS-C3560G-24PS
50~ Cisco IP Phones 7960 Series

2x Dell PowerConnect 5548
1x Linux Box running Zoom CallRec
```

All the IP phones are 100mb, and the desktop computer plug into the phone.  Most of the desktops are gigabit.

We use Zoom to record our VoIP calls.  Zoom is using a Cisco SPAN to do the recording of the calls.  That functionality seems to be missing in the DELL switch.  I ran this command from the Cisco switch Zoom is plugged into.

```
SW-4#show monitor
Session 1
---------
Type                   : Remote Destination Session
Source RSPAN VLAN      : 901
Destination Ports      : Gi0/21-22
    Encapsulation      : Native
          Ingress      : Disabled
```

Ports 21 and 22 is what Zoom is plugged into.  I'm not sure what vlan 901 is for, nothing seems to be on that vlan, but all the ports are setup as trunking for vlans 10, 20, 254, 901.  All the VoIP equipment is on vlan 10 (10.1.10.0/24).  Vlan 20 (10.0.0.0/24) is for data. vlan 254 (10.1.254.0/24) is management.  We are trying to move from Cisco switches to Dell switches.  This call recording seems like the last problem (I hope).  We don't have to keep zoom, but I'm not sure what to replace it with, any suggestions?

The Zoom documents talk about active vs passive recording.  We are using passive, which requires Cisco SPAN.  The active recording might fix the problem, but I'm not sure how much work it's going to be.  So I was hoping for some good advice.

Comment: You should think about rewriting the title of the question to be more in line with your actual question for a couple of reasons.  As it stands now it looks like a what should I buy question that tends to get closed here.  Also the current title may not get the attention of someone who may know how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Dell switches it's called Port Mirroring (as opposed to port spanning). Look in the Port Mirroring section of the Ports section in the user manual.

http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/network/pc5548/en/UG/PDF/en_ug.pdf